# Adding content of file as mail body while sending mail using telnet

Tags: email, command-line, smtp, telnet

I want to send the content of a log file in the mail body using telnet service. I have been using following commands on command line to trigger a mail:

```
telnet mydomain.com 25
helo mydomain.com
mail from:senderdomain.com
rcpt to:recieverdomain.com
data
Hi.. This is for test!
.
quit
```

How to add a subject and the contents of a text file in this mail? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to easily do it using a plain telnet session.

If you need to send a mail attachment, you need to follow [RFC 2045, MIME](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045), and RFC 2046 (specifically the [Mixed subtype section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-5.1.3)). You'll have to format the email according to these RFCs, and to encode your attachment, usually using base64. That's a lot work, a pain to do with gool ol' dos commands.

Your easiest option would be to use a command line tool, like [BLAT for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/blat/).

Answer (score 0):

Like @NicolasRiousset points out, it's probably too painful without a proper client, but if the text file contains well-formatted plain text (7-bit US-ASCII only; no text line longer than ... uh, slightly less than 1,000 characters) you can do something like

```
#!/bin/bash
case $# in 2) ;; *) echo "Usage: $0 <host> <filename.txt>"; exit 0;; esac
( printf $'%\r\n' "helo mydomain.com" \
    "mail from:<user@senderdomain.com>" \
    "rcpt to:<rcpt@recieverdomain.com>"
    "data"
    "Subject: $2"
    ""
  sed $'s/^\./../;s/$/\r/' "$2"
  printf $'%\r\n' "." "quit"
) |
telnet "$1" 25
```

There may be timing issues; `nc` might work better than plain old `telnet`.  A proper tool would wait for the SMTP server's response after each command, and check its return code.

I use Bash C-style strings for (some sort of) portability, but (e.g.) your `sed` might still not play along nicely.  In addition to replacing the line breaks with CRLF:s, the script performs dot stuffing as required by RFC5321.

Notice also that your `mail from:` and `rcpt to:` commands were slightly incorrect.